# Scraping structured information from hundreds of Word documents?

Tags: database, parsing, ms-word, scrape

I've been tasked with extracting some structured information from hundreds of human readable documents (mostly MS Word) and to put it into a database. The data is pretty much embedded in tables throughout the entire document but there's a lot of text between the tables and although the documents are very similar in structure, there are a few differences. The documents are changed fairly often (we get an updated version every few months)

So far the only viable option i can think of is to manually go trough all the documents and insert/update the information but I thought I'd ask here if anyone think it's possible to scrape the documents in some way?

Oh, and the data has to be fairly correct...

Comment: What format are the files in? .doc, .docx, ...?

Comment: @0xA3 a mix of mostly doc and docx but also some pdfs

Comment: Putting the PDFs aside for the moment, would it help to copy all of the tables in all the Word docs into a single document?

Comment: @plutext Don't think so, i'd still have to find the correct table (there are about 20 different tables in each file) and with hundreds of individual documents and updates coming in the final document would be really long and hard to maintain.

Comment: So is there anything about the table that differentiates it from all the others in the document ie uniquely identifies it?

Comment: There are headings in the vicinity (there is generally some other text between the actual header and the tables) and the data in the tables can be parsed and checked to do some more obvious categorising.

Answer (score 2):

I did similar work (without tables though) using a [converter from RTF to FO](http://rtf-to-xml.com/).

You have convert docs to RTF, and then to FO, which gives you a nice XML structure of the document. You can then easily parse it and scrape the data.